# Tutorials on LDPC error correction codes

Tags: reference-request, coding-theory, information-theory

Please consider this as soft question.

Recently, I have been studying channel coding and in particular error correction codes. I am looking for best tutorial (easy to understand) on LDPC error correction codes.

Including the decoding of such codes too.

I am looking forward for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you familiar with linear codes, first? Generation matrix? Parity check matrix? Syndromes, and so on. In other words, how far is your knowledge in linear encoding/decoding?

Comment: i hate to say this but not much.

Comment: That's the point you can get started then :) In particular, I do not know any book example, sorry. But it can help others who want to help you who do know some. :)

Comment: so do you believe i should start with linear codes?

Comment: I like [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/spielman/ECC/handouts.html). LDPC codes come about a month into the notes and no prior experience with coding theory or information theory is assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Channel codes - Classical and Modern" by William E. Ryan and Shu Lin should be a great place to learn about both linear codes and LDPC codes in particular as the book devotes a huge part to the latter topic with a self-contained introduction to the former.