# Finding range of $m$ in $x^2+mx+6$.

Tags: quadratics

Find the range of values of $m$ in the quadratic equation $x^2+mx+6=0$ such that both the roots of the equation $\alpha,\beta<1$.

My attempt - it is given that

$\alpha<1$ and $\beta<1$

$\rightarrow \alpha+\beta<2$

But $\alpha+\beta=-m$

Thus $m>-2$.

But this solution doesn't involve the coefficient term i.e. $6$.

**Any solution to the above question is appreciated.**

Answer (score 4):

You made a logical fallacy as old as time.

What you have proven is:

> If $\alpha, \beta<1$, then $m>-2$

What you ***HAVE NOT PROVEN*** is:

> If $m>-2$, then $\alpha, \beta < 1$.

You can easily see that the second statement is false, since if $m=0>-2$, the equation has no real solutions.

Comment: Sir so how do we find the range of m.please can u post ur answer.

Comment: @AxelBlaze Try to write the explicit formulas for $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: @gebra But the statement "for all $m>-2$, $a,b<1$" is **false**. That's my whole point. If $m=0$ is a true statement, then $a,b<1$ is not a true statement.

Comment: it depends on how you interpret the question, I would consider the bound $a,b < 1$ only a statement about the real part of a and b. If the imaginary part must be 0, then they should state that, or otherwise state that both roots of the equation a,b, < 1 are in the set of reals.

Comment: @gebra Look, however you want to spin this, the answer to the question "when are both roots of $x^2 + mx + 6$ smaller than $1$" is **not** "when $m>-2$". Also, the standard way of interpreting $x<1$ is "$x$ is real and smaller than $1$".

Answer (score 2):

This is a step-by-step description of how I would do it. There might be more clever ways out there, and there might be unanticipated problems with this approach, but it is the first thing I would try:

1. Write an explicit formula for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (it should use both the constant coefficient $6$ and the linear coefficient $m$)
2. Decide which of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is the biggest
3. Set that root to be less than $1$
4. Solve

Answer (score 2):

As you see solving for $x$, one can start from the system $$\begin {cases} y=mx \\ \\ y=-x^2-6 \end {cases}$$ studying the intersections of a generic line passing through the origin ($m$ is just its slope) with a (fixed) parabola.

After checking the lines of tangency with $m=\pm \sqrt {24}$ and the line passing through the point $(1,-7)$, it is easy to deduce that both the roots are less than $1$ for every (and only) $m \ge \sqrt {24}$ .

Comment: P.S. Employing some google-fu, I've understood whence the system; but is this a purely graphical way, or is this system solvable algebraically?

Comment: It is essentially a graphical way.

Comment: Thanks! It's a nice way to flex one's imagination regarding quadratics.

Comment: But it would be hard to find graphically that m should equal plus-minus the square root of 24, I guess... maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: It would be impossible, I would say. The key values of $m$ are found analytically.

Answer (score 1):

> Find the range of values of $m$ in the quadratic equation $x^2+mx+6=0$ such that both the roots of the equation $\alpha,\beta<1$.

Our graph has its wings pointing upwards. When both roots are less than one, both wings of the function's graph transect the OX axis *to the left* of the point $x=1$.

In order to be sure that both transection points are to the left of $x=1$, we need to know:

1. There exist two transection points: hence, $D>0$
   (If $D=0$, there will only be one transection point, meaning only one root; if $D<0$, there will exist no transection points: no roots).
2. If we draw a vertical line from $x=1$, it will strike the graph *above* the OX axis: hence $f(1)>0$
   (Indeed, if it strikes the graph below the OX axis, that would mean that the point $x=1$ lies between the two roots)
3. But what if it will strike the *left* wing of the graph, not the right one? What if the whole shebang lies to the right of $x=1$? In order to exclude this possibility, let's say that the lowest point of the graph should also lie to the left of $x=1$. Hence, $x_0<1$. The formula for $x_0$ is $x_0=\frac{-B}{2A}$

Then I would unite these three conditions in a system and solve it.

[image]

Comment: If you are interested, your method is described by A.Tartinville in his [book](http://www.amazon.com/Th%C3%A9orie-%C3%89quations-In%C3%A9quations-Premier-Inconnue/dp/114880076X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1440009464&sr=1-1&keywords=tartinville) (1886). By the way, x0=-B/A or -B/2A ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo - thank you for the correction! It's $\frac{-B}{2A}$ of course!

Comment: @TonyPiccolo - thanks for the mention of Tartinville. I took the method from [a website](http://mathus.ru/math/parameter-quad2.pdf) run by [Igor Yakovlev](http://mathus.ru/me.php), a Moscow Physics Institute graduate and a math teacher.

Comment: @CopperKettle Can u please also send the link for the translated page to english?I am an Indian and I can't understand Russian!

Comment: @AxelBlaze - sorry, I have no information on similar self-study pages in English. The webpage is in Russian, of course.

Comment: @AxelBlaze - hey, I've got an idea: you might ask a "soft question" at StackExchange, providing the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1402687/126401) to my answer and requesting weblinks to similar pages in English (i mean with explanations on quadratics)

Comment: @CopperKettle A nice idea.But unfortunately I have no idea about soft questions as I have never posted them.Still I will try to post one.I thus request you to please edit my question if there's any mistake in it or if the language might be improved.And should I place my soft question on maths stackexchange or any other stack exchange community?

Comment: @AxelBlaze - place it here, on maths SE. I've seen such questions. Here's an **[example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287259/tutorials-on-ldpc-error-correction-codes)**

Comment: @CopperKettle CAn you please go through my soft question and suggest corrections (if any). (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403858/soft-question-weblinks-to-pages-with-explanation-on-quadratics)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the pq-formula:
$$x_{1/2} = -\frac{m}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{m^2}{4}-6}$$
from that we ca deduce:
1) $m^2 \geq 24$, because the radiant under the root can't be negative
2)
$$-\frac{m}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{m^2}{4}-6} < 1$$
just solve that and you have your range